# Raster calculator and Saga Raster calculator gives different output when multiplying rasters (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, rusle

I need to multiply 5 different raster to get my end product. However when I calculate it in the Raster Calculator the answer is double the amount I get when I calculate it in the Saga Raster Calculator. Why?

My formula in the Raster Calculator is:

`"C_factor@1"*"K_factor@1"*"LS_factor@1"*"P_factor@1"*"R_factor@1"`

I do the same in the SAGA Calculator: (only the names are different)

`a*b*c*d*e`

Comment: Works for me, although initially I hadn't realised that there's a "base layer" that is `a` in the SAGA formula, and you mustn't select this in the selected layers that maps to the other letters `b` to `e`. The "additional layers (optional)" dialog should have four layers selected. I got that wrong, selecting all 5 layers and ended up with 4x expected amount... And some warning messages: `Warning: The number of supplied grids exceeds the number of variables in formula. (6 > 5)`

Comment: Thanks! But do you get the same result multiplying layers in the raster calculator and the SAGA raster calculator? Because my problem is that I do not, and I don't know which answer is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, I made some test rasters that multiplied to 105, which I got with the QGIS raster, so I knew that was right. First effort with SAGA got me 420, which was 4x105. Think this was because mis-specifying the a,b,c,d,e in the SAGA plugin resulted in effectively a*a*b*c*d and that was 420, but I'm not sure how SAGA would behave in these circs. Once I got the layer spec right, I got 105 with SAGA as well.